# How to control concurrency on sidekiq by model instance?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sidekiq

I have a Customer model and a Message model and am using Sidekiq for many things.

Whenever I receive a new Message, I spawn a worker that records the info for that Message and then updates a few columns on Customer.

The problem I'm having is that if I get a bunch of new Messages at once, let's say 10 of them, all 10 messages try to update the Customer based on the state of the customer when the worker read the customer. This is causing weird issues. For example, I need to increment a counter every time Customer goes from state 'closed' to 'open'. All 10 messages spawn at the same time and read the customer as 'closed' and then all 10 messages trigger the customer to change from closed to open even though only the first message should have triggered that state change. All other messages shouldn't have done anything because the customer was already open.

What is the right way to handle this situation?

Is there any way to specify that sidekiq only uses concurrency if the customers are different?

Answer (score 0):

Read up on ActiveRecord optimistic and pessimistic locking.